# Using Cookies versus Sessions for login

Tags: session, cookies, authentication

I'm building a basic login script from a book that uses sessions to manage wether a user is logged in or not.

This is great, but when I close my browser, and then reopen it, I have to log back in.
Whereas, with Facebook for example, I remained logged in, even if I have closed my browser. I'm guessing this is done using cookies. Is it safe to use cookies? How long should this cookie last? Sometimes websites explicitly say, "please remember to log out at the end of your visit". Why would this be necessary?

Currently my script is kinda like this:

```
session_start();

if (is_set($_POST["login_button_pressed"])){
     if (form_verified_successfully()){
          $user_details = get_user_details_from_database();
          $_SESSION['username'] = $user_details['username'];
     }
}
```

Would it be easy to modify the above to work with cookies? And if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A `cookie` is a small text file that is saved to a temporary directory on the user's harddrive. This cookie can be accessed by the browser that placed it there. It can hold data such as previously visited URLs (posts the user read vs hasn't read), the user's credentials or even the contents of the users cart or a post they didn't finish writing in a forum. You will choose how long the cookie is valid for that system, most common that I have seen are 24 hours, 7 days, 14 days and 30 days.

A `session` is attached to the actual piece of software interacting with the web server, ie, a browser, command prompt or other application. Once the browser is closed or the application is shutdown the session data will be lost.

Reasons you might want to have the user login again, the data you have granted access to is very private information that another user who grabs the computer 15 minutes later shouldn't have access to (banking, account settings) or the data you have given to the user is time sensitive and you want to force the user to sign in again and be given fresh data when they come back.

Most social networking sites like Facebook, LinkedIn, Google+, Twitter and several other forums and blogs will give you a cookie to let you stay logged in for up to a month or longer so you can easily come back and look through the site and post to your profile. However, if you go to change your account settings they will prompt you to login again and will only give you access to those pieces of the site during your current session. This is for security reasons.

I hope this helps out. For a quick reference, run a Google search on `sessions vs cookies`. You should be able to find a relevant article to whatever language/platform you are using. There are great articles out there for PHP, Java, .net and others that discuss advantages, disadvantages and best practices.

**Changing to a cookie:**
As for your last question, it shouldn't be very hard to change to using a cookie. Most likely it will be referenced via `_COOKIE` instead of `_SESSION`, but you will have to tell the cookie what information to hold and how long to stay active. A quick Google search for `setting cookie [language]` should provide plenty of tutorials. Replace `[language]` with either PHP, Java, Spring, .net, etc.

Comment: hows your experience go  from a performance perspective do you notice the difference? I am curious if a lot of sessions scale:

https://hackernoon.com/using-session-cookies-vs-jwt-for-authentication-sd2v3vci

"JWTs are widely used as it scales better than that of a session-cookie based ... stored on the client-side ... session server memory... potential issue large userbase at once"

Im a noob btw so if this is inaccurate ty for any corrections